# python http server hide console

Tags: python, http, console, http.server

I am trying to do a script that is hosting my file on my local network, here's my code :

```
import os
import getpass

os.system('python -m http.server --directory C:/Users/'+getpass.getuser())
```

But the probleme is that the http console is showing on my Desktop and that's annoying ! so I tried to hide by renaming the file in .pyw but it's not working.

Have you any idea on how to hide this console ? Thank you :D

Answer (score 2):

On Linux you can use [Nohup](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nohup.1.html) to ignore the HUP signal.

You could add nohup on your code like this:

```
import os
import getpass

os.system('nohup python -m http.server --directory C:/Users/'+getpass.getuser())
```

---

**Update**

Solution for windows

```
import os
import subprocess
import getpass

env = os.environ
directory = 'C:/Users/'+getpass.getuser()
proc = subprocess.Popen(['python', '-m', 'http.server', '--directory', directory], env=env)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply ! Unfortunately I am on windows 10 >.< I tried to do START /MIN main.py but it's still on taskbar

Comment: @Lun4rIum check the update.

Comment: I tried your code but it's still showing the console. I will try to hide it it batch I think

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're on Linux (or other unix based OS), you can detach the process from the console after starting the server.

Here is one way to do it with [`screen` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Invoking-Screen)

```
sudo apt install -Y screen
```

And then

```
screen -d -m "python3 script.py"
```

Where `script.py` is the snippet you have shared.

[Reference for the flags](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Invoking-Screen)

> ...
>
> `-d -m`
>
> Start screen in detached mode. This creates a new session but doesn’t attach to it. This is useful for system startup scripts.

Comment: Look at the path!

Comment: thanks for your reply ! Unfortunately I am on windows 10 >.< I tried to do START /MIN main.py but it's still on taskbar

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it, with a VBS script:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "main.py" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

Just replace `main.py` with the path of your script.